# How to set the autoSize to UIbutton according to Title of Button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have  buttons. For getting title of the button I am sending request to server and than set the title of Button. Now I need to set the autosize resizing to this buttons. How to do this ? I set to CharacterWrap in Line break in identity inspectors of button. Now the text is showing in multiple lines but I also need to resize the button because some texts are too big and some are too small. Here is how it looks like in Storyboard and constraints with constraints everything ok I just need to resize button.
[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBInspectable var selectedColor : UIColor = UIColor.init(red: 34/255, green: 89/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
@IBInspectable var normalColor : UIColor = UIColor.init(red: 59/255, green: 169/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1.0)


@IBOutlet weak var variant4button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var variant3button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var variant2Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var variant1button: UIButton!
```

Here is that 4 buttons.
Here I am setting the title :

```
if (numberOfVariants.count != 0) {
            let questionTextView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
            questionTextView.text = "\(Questions[indexPath.row].content!)"
            variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            let numberOfVars = numberOfVariants[indexPath.row]
            if (numberOfVars == 2) {
                variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant3.isHidden = true
                variant4.isHidden = true
            }
            else if (numberOfVars == 3){
                variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant3.setTitle(Variants[2+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant4.isHidden = true
            }
            else if (numberOfVars == 4) {
                variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant3.setTitle(Variants[2+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
                variant4.setTitle(Variants[3+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
            }
        }
```

for Jaydeep Vyas
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you have to create class uibutton and assign this class to required button

```
class AutoSizableButton: UIButton
{
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
        {
        get {
            let labelSize = titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)) ?? CGSize.zero
            let reqiredButtonSize = CGSize(width: labelSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right, height: labelSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)

            return reqiredButtonSize
        }
    }
}
```

also don't fogot to add this in viewDidload

```
self.btnDemo.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.btnDemo.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: It is not working, I added this code but everything is the same. Please checkout I have added the photo to question

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов its perfectly working for me have assign any new constraints or forget to assign class to the button

Comment: I think that problem in the TableViewCell my cell not allowing to change the size to this button. Can you give me your email? I'll send you and maybe you will understand better ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ktayuvar3ywpcg/infoBank%202.zip?dl=0    login-sergey  password - 123456

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149467/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Try this programmatically :

```
- (float) getRequiredWidth : (UIButton *)button
{
    float requiredWidth =
    [button.titleLabel.text
     boundingRectWithSize:button.frame.size
     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:button.font }
     context:nil]
    .size.width;

    return requiredWidth;
}
```

in your code :

```
float totalWidth = [self getRequiredWidth : yourButton];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(yourButtonX, yourButtonY, totalWidth, yourButtonHeight)
```

Comment: I have no any constraints to width of button, and it is not working. Size not changing